# Azure Function - Exception: ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, azure-functions

I'm getting this weird message even thought I already install via Pip

```
Worker failed to function id 2c284181-1e21-4200-b5ea-b7d226696206.
[2023-11-30T03:24:02.694Z] Result: Failure
[2023-11-30T03:24:02.694Z] Exception: ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
[2023-11-30T03:24:02.694Z]         its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
[2023-11-30T03:24:02.694Z]         your python interpreter from there. Troubleshooting Guide: https://aka.ms/functions-modulenotfound
[2023-11-30T03:24:02.695Z] Stack:   File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-functions-core-tools/bin/workers/python/3.9/OSX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 314, in _handle__function_load_request
[2023-11-30T03:24:02.695Z]     func = loader.load_function(
[2023-11-30T03:24:02.695Z]   File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-functions-core-tools/bin/workers/python/3.9/OSX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py", line 42, in call
[2023-11-30T03:24:02.695Z]     raise extend_exception_message(e, message)
[2023-11-30T03:24:02.695Z]   File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-functions-core-tools/bin/workers/python/3.9/OSX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py", line 40, in call
[2023-11-30T03:24:02.695Z]     return func(*args, **kwargs)
[2023-11-30T03:24:02.695Z]   File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-functions-core-tools/bin/workers/python/3.9/OSX/X64/azure_functions_worker/loader.py", line 85, in load_function
[2023-11-30T03:24:02.695Z]     mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname)
[2023-11-30T03:24:02.695Z]   File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
[2023-11-30T03:24:02.695Z]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[2023-11-30T03:24:02.695Z]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
[2023-11-30T03:24:02.695Z]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
[2023-11-30T03:24:02.695Z]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[2023-11-30T03:24:02.696Z]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
[2023-11-30T03:24:02.696Z]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
[2023-11-30T03:24:02.696Z]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
[2023-11-30T03:24:02.696Z]   File "/Users/zero/Documents/Github/project/fc/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
[2023-11-30T03:24:02.696Z]     import numpy as np
[2023-11-30T03:24:02.696Z]   File "/Users/zero/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 135, in <module>
[2023-11-30T03:24:02.696Z]     raise ImportError(msg) from e
```

__init__.py

```
import os
import re
import logging
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np

import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('A function processed a request.')

    return func.HttpResponse(
        "success",
        status_code=200,
    )
```

requirements.txt

```
numpy
```

[image]

Comment: Please share your `function code` and `requirements.txt`(if you have).

Comment: you may check the updated question above @PravallikaKV

Comment: Does this happens locally or deployed?

Comment: @PaulH it happens locally

Comment: @Nurdin, Try removing the version and just give the package `numpy` in requirements.txt.

Comment: @PravallikaKV the error message remain same...

Comment: Did you create and activate virtual environment?

Comment: yes I did @PravallikaKV.

Comment: Are you installing the packages using the command `pip install -r requirements.txt`?

Comment: yes, I already did that......

Comment: How did you invoke the local server?

Comment: Im using this command, func start

Comment: @Nurdin, uninstall Numpy package `pip install numpy` and install again. Relaunch the python interpreter in any other directory and run the function.

Comment: how to relaunch the python interpreter in any other directory ???

Answer (score 0):

The error could be due to the improper installation of the **NumPy** package.

To resolve this issue:

- Go to your ***Project folder*** and launch the ***Python Interpreter***(command palette=>search for `Python: Select Interpreter`).
- Uninstall **NumPy** package and install again by running below commands in Terminal:

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy
```

---

I have created a simple python Azure function with ***Python version 3.11.6*** and imported ***NumPy*** Package.

**Code Snippet:**

```py
import azure.functions as func
import logging

import numpy as np

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.route(route="HttpTrigger", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
def HttpTrigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    arr = np.array([1, 2, 3])

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully with {arr}")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )
```

**requirements.txt:**

```
azure-functions
numpy
```

- Created and Activated Virtual Environment:

```
py -m venv .venv  
.venv\scripts\activate
```

- Installing the required packages with the command `pip install -r requirements.txt`:

[image]

- ***Installed the package under .venv/Lib/site-packages:***

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

**References:**

[Troubleshooting — NumPy v1.26 Manual](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html)

Comment: still same, same error message

Comment: Create a simple python function, import `numpy` package and check if you're still facing the same.

Comment: It's still the same as previously....

Comment: Create a new folder in `c:/` folder and implement the same.